# How to Use $unwind in mongoose aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have to use below collection and i can use $unwind in mongoose aggregate function.

but the query did not return empty array,I am using mongodb version 3.0.8.

```
[{"ProjectName": "AAA",
"Emp": [
    {
        "EmpID": {
            "$oid": "123"
        },
        "Rating": 4
    }
]},
 {
     "ProjectName": "BBB","Emp": []
 }]
```

I have to use below code,

```
Pro.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$Emp" },
    { $group: {
    "_id": '$_id',
    "ProjectName": { "$first": "$ProjectName" },
    }},
    ], function (err, result) { 
    });
```

but result return only one document.

so please give some solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you read the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#missing-field) about the behavior of the `$unwind`?

Comment: yes i have....but i am using heroku for the mongoDB(version3.0.8)...is there any way to fix in 3.0.8 version....